# How do I limit file size for image and video seperately using express fileupload?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express-fileupload package to upload files to minio object storage. Now, I want to limit my filesize to 1 Mb for images and 10 Mb for video.

Answer (score 0):

Create two separates middleware instances with different options for images and for videos.

```
const videoUpload = fileUpload({
  useTempFiles: true,
  tempFileDir : '/tmp/',
  createParentPath: true
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
});

const imageUpload = fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
  limits: { fileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 },
});
```

Point them to the different routes.

```
   app.use('/upload/video', videoUpload);
   app.use('/upload/image', imageUpload);
```